# Woocommerce get products showing in archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get all the products showing in an archive page of my shop. I want to get their ids. I'm using a hook of mine which runs on wp_head and checks

```
if(is_product_category())
```

I want to somehow access the query for the products and get their ids.

```
if(is_product_category()) {
    $current_category = get_queried_object();
    $category_id = $current_category->term_id;
    $category_name = $current_category->name;
```

This is the code i have so far in order to get the current category id

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the archive page, the main query should contain the posts. The easiest way is to grab the ID's from the "posts" property from the $wp_query global. There's a utility function called wp_list_pluck which gets each index from an array of arrays, so you end up with an array of IDs instead.

```
global $wp_query;
$ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query->posts, "ID" );
```

Note that while wp_list_pluck does use a loop to iterate through the array, it is better than using the WordPress loop style of have_posts(), the_post(). This is because it is not moving all the data around between the $wp_query and $post globals, nor do you have to mess with resetting the query.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i have found the answer, it was rather simple, here it is for everyone struggles with the same issue.

```
    woocommerce_product_loop_start(false);
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
    }
    woocommerce_product_loop_end(false);
```

With this the woocommerce loop is called again for the current page so we can grab the info we want. 
PS : Do we have to reset the query after it's done?

Comment: After a custom query you should call ```wp_reset_postdata()```. But in this case you are working with the original loop, so you want to use ```wp_reset_query()``` instead. If you don't run these, any loop that happens later would start at the last post of the loop because it has already gone through them all. I posted an alternate answer that doesn't involve a loop for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow here for Getting woocommerce Product ID

http://www.remicorson.com/easily-find-woocommerce-products-id/

just create one folder inside plugin folder and paste the code there or you can paste the code  in theme function.php file also. Hope this will help you.