# WooCommerce get all the SKU of products on current shop and category pages

Tags: php, woocommerce

How can we get the SKU of all the products viewed on the current page? 
`is_shop() is_product_category() is_search()`
The following code only displays the first items SKU:

```
global $product;
$product->get_sku();
```

I would need to get the SKU of all the viewed products to use in Google Ads tag dataLayer. 
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169727/woocommerce-get-products-showing-in-archive-page